# Configuring Jenkins for selenium web driver tests

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

**Setup on Mac:**
Jenkins
Maven
TestNG
Selenium Webdriver

**Issue:**
While running the test from Jenkins I am getting the following error
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
connection refused

Note : I am able to run the same suite xml from Eclipse with no error.

**Code:**

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "//eclipse-     Oxygen/aaa/src/test/java/aa/aaa/geckodriver 4");


 System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

[image: error message]

Comment: as it says in the error `Permission denied` on the port -> `Failed to establish the default connection to the WindowServer`. Make sure that Jenkins cann access this port.

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Comment: If your browser/driver are compatible, most likely your Jenkins account doesn't have a proper access, while you (interactive user) do. SO make sure jenkins user is either same as interactive user, or has enough permissions.